# Celery beat stuck on Starting

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, scheduled-tasks

We have microservices, which are connected using grpc server and the tasks are run through our own task manager which uses celery and rabbitmq

After I ran celery -A celery_worker.celery worker -B --loglevel=info

```
[2023-06-14 18:12:24,827: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://oneassure-admin:**@127.0.0.1:5672/oneassure
[2023-06-14 18:12:24,838: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2023-06-14 18:12:25,860: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2023-06-14 18:12:25,883: INFO/MainProcess] celery@devdcodes ready.
[2023-06-14 18:12:26,354: INFO/Beat] beat: Starting...
```

I tried restarting the celery terminal and I was expecting the beat to start and not get stuck on starting

Comment: Can you share the configuration of the periodic tasks? From your input we don't know if there's even anything to execute so maybe this is correct.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. I do believe it is something to do witht he celerybeat-schedule.db file. On first attempt. The celery beat service complained that the db was corrupted and also failed to removed it because of some missing module. After I tried manually removed the db with the native `rm` command, the Celery beat service was stuck on starting. Am sure the db is reconstructed when starting the db the next time you run it. Unless, there are some intermediate steps to do in order to reconstruct the celerybeat-schedule.db file.

Answer (score 0):

From my observation, the Celery beat service will be on `starting...` because it is waiting to send a task to the celery worker service. Once, the time scheduled to send the task has arrived, then the console output will change to indicate that the task has been sent.

To check if your celery commands are working correctly? Check in your schedule settings and change the `schedule` setting of your task to `crontab()`. This will send the command every minute.

**Please note that changing the schedule to `crontab()`, which sends a task every 60 seconds,  is just for testing purposes and see the output quickly. Remember to change back the schedule setting to your desired cron interval**